# How to standardize a random variable up to the fourth moment?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

Suppose $X$ is a random variable such that $\operatorname*{E}(X^n) < \infty$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. We can standardize $X$ up to the second moment by letting $Y = \frac{X - \operatorname*{E}(X)}{\sqrt{\operatorname*{E}\left(X^2\right) - \operatorname*{E}(X)^2}}$ such that $\operatorname*{E}(Y) = 0$ and $\operatorname*{E}(Y^2) = 1$. How do we construct a random variable $Z$ from $X$ such that it satisfies the following properties? The right-hand side can be any constant. I picked 0's and 1's simply because they look nice.

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\operatorname*{E}(Z) &= 0 \\
\operatorname*{E}(Z^2) &= 1 \\
\operatorname*{E}(Z^3) &= 0 \\
\operatorname*{E}(Z^4) &= 1 \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I would imagine we need some higher-order operations like square root or maybe logarithm, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: Is the only requirement that $Z$ is some function of $X$?  Or does there need to be some other properties in common between $Z$ and $X$?

Comment: @user6247850 I don't have other requirements at the top of my mind. Of course, the mapping from $X$ to $Z$ should be as simple as possible, where simplicity is measured by computational cost in terms of FLOP. I am looking for a generalization of the mapping from $X$ to $Y$, which is simply a linear transformation.

Comment: Note that $Y$ simply is of the form $aX + b.$ From high-school you know that in general, 4 equations with 2 unknowns cannot be solved  (upto exceptional cases).

Answer (score 9):

No, this is not always possible.  First, by Jensen's inequality, $E[Z^4] = E[(Z^2)^2] \ge E[Z^2]^2$, with equality holding iff $Z$ is actually a constant.  That immediately rules out $E[Z^4] = E[Z^2]$ unless $Z^2$ is a constant.

More generally, if we don't require $\mathbb{E}[Z^4] = 1$ but still want to specify some value for $\mathbb{E}[Z^3]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Z^4]$, we still can't do this in general.  For example, consider the case where $X=x_1$ with probability $p$ and $X=x_2$ with probability $q=1-p$.  If $Z = f(X)$, then $Z$ can only have the values $a = f(x_1)$ or $b = f(x_2)$.  We have that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Z] &= pa + qb \\
\mathbb{E}[Z^2] &= pa^2 + qb^2 \\
\mathbb{E}[Z^3] &= pa^3 + qb^3 \\
\mathbb{E}[Z^4] &= pa^4 + qb^4.
\end{align*}
If we require $E[Z] = 0$ and $E[Z^2] = 1$, that immediately requires $a=\frac{-qb}{p}$ and $b^2 = \frac{p}{q^2+qp} = \frac{p}{q}$.  This specifies $a$ and $b$ up to a sign, so we have no chance to choose $a$ and $b$ to make $\mathbb{E}[Z^3]$ or $\mathbb{E}[Z^4]$ any particular value.

Comment: That's interesting. I guess this counter-example also explains why we don't have generalizations of the location-scale family where we can specify the third and fourth moment.

Answer (score 0):

Not  *every* combination of moments can represent a probability distribution $P$ because probability distributions are positive and normalized functions (as noted in the previous answer), however, you can transform one continuous distribution to another using the [inverse transformation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), so you can always transform the distribution to the (e.g.) Gaussian distribution with the Gaussian standard moments.